# mysql, select rows that satisfy join and column value when join equals null

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

I have two tables the first one called staff with columns id, name, defaultSel and the second called staffRels with columns id, staffID, etc. I want to select those rows from the staff table with a presence at the staffRels table along with those that do not appear in the staffRels table but have defaultSel column set to 1. i have the following so far but with not very good results giving me either a whole bunch of rows i don't want or less depending on how i format the case in the where clause.

```
SELECT staff.id, staff.name FROM staff 
LEFT JOIN staffRels 
ON staff.id = staffRels.staffID 
WHERE CASE staffRels.id WHEN null THEN staff.defaultSel=1 ELSE staff.defaultSel=0 END
```

Anything to clear my view on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM staff s LEFT JOIN
     staffRels sr
     ON s.id = sr.staffID 
WHERE (sr.id IS NOT NULL) OR (s.defaultSel = 1) ;
```

This has the possibility of duplicates.  You might prefer:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM staff s
WHERE s.defaultSel = 1 OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM staffRels sr WHERE s.id = sr.staffID);
```

Answer (score 0):

put the case into the select clause.

```
SELECT staff.id, staff.name,CASE staffRels.id WHEN null THEN staff.defaultSel=1 ELSE staff.defaultSel=0 END as staff.defaultSelFROM staff 
LEFT JOIN staffRels 
ON staff.id = staffRels.staffID
```